# How to fix the DB::goto frame?

Tags: perl, debugging, stack-trace

When I run this script as `perl -d:DB t.pl`
$ cat t.pl

```
sub t { }
sub sb {
   goto &t;  # << The DB::goto is called from here
}
sb( a => 3 )
```

$ cat Devel/DB.pm

```
package DB;

BEGIN {
    $^P |= 0x80;
}

sub DB {
}

sub goto {
    local $"  =  ' - '; #"
    my $level =  0;
    while( my @frame = caller($level++) ) {
        print "@frame[0..3,5]\n";
    }
}

sub sub {
    return &$DB::sub;
}


1;
sub t { }
sub sb {
   goto &t;  # << The DB::goto is called from here
}
sb( a => 3 )
```

The 'caller' called form DB::goto return next info:

```
DB - Devel/DB.pm - 19 - DB::goto - 
main - t.pl - 5 - main::t -
```

Because the **DB::goto is called by perl internals as ordinary sub here** I expect next output:

```
main - t.pl - 3 - DB::goto - 
main - t.pl - 5 - main::t -
```

Is it possible to fix that behaviour? If yes
At which direction to dig to fix that?

Comment: You code returns `Illegal character in prototype for main::sb : a => 3 at ./1.pl line 9.
Prototype mismatch: sub main::sb: none vs (a => 3) at ./1.pl line 9.`. Can you fix it and give more details on how to get the output?

Comment: I have fixed. And create appropriate modules.

Comment: Weird. When I add a debug print after the `goto` call, it doesn't get printed, but when I change it to `DB::goto`, it gets printed.

Comment: @choroba That's because `DB::goto` is just a regular subroutine; there's no `goto` opcode when you do that.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: But how is it possible that the opcode doesn't call CORE::goto?

Comment: @choroba: the DB::goto is called by perl internals when the script is runned with -d flag. DB::goto does nothing, It just a hook that signals about that the 'goto' OP will be executed at the script. So after &t returns, the next OP code will be OP code that follows sb( a=> 3), not that which follow 'goto &t'. Therefore your print after 'goto &t' did not executed.

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution is:

```
t.pl:5  sb( a => 3 )
  [enter DB::sub]
Devel/DB.pm:19  return &$DB::sub;
  [enter main::sb]
t.pl:3  goto &t;
  [enter DB::goto]
```

When `goto` is reached, the most recent function call was in Devel/DB.pm on line 19, so that's what `caller(0)` returns. (Remember, `goto &NAME` alters the call stack.)

But it sounds like you want to report the line number and file where `goto` was invoked. Unfortunately, I don't think you can do this with `caller`, because `caller` isn't even aware of `goto`:

```
sub foo {
    goto &bar;
}

sub bar {
    print join ' - ', caller, "\n";
}

foo();

__END__
main - bar - 9 -  # line 9 is where foo() is called, not goto &bar
```

One possible workaround would be to store the filename and line number of the last executed command in `DB::DB`, then print that value before your stack trace in `DB::goto`. I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this, though.

Comment: I have tried that workaround, but when the $DB::single = 0 the DB::DB is not called. I set it to zero because want to go to the next breakpoint.

Comment: 1. How DB::goto and from where is invoked? Is it common sub call?

Comment: 2. >When goto is reached, the most recent function call was in Devel/DB.pm on line 19. But if I print callstack just before 'goto &t' it show that most recent function call was in: 'main t.pl 5 main::sb'. I am confused (

Comment: 1. DB::goto is called from Perl_pp_goto, the `goto` opcode, in [pp_ctl.c](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/maint-5.22/pp_ctl.c#L2979) in the Perl source. I *think* it's invoked like a normal sub, but I'm not quite familiar enough with Perl's internals to be sure. However, keep in mind that `goto` changes the call stack; I haven't traced through this yet, but I'm guessing that the call stack has already been changed by the time DB::goto is invoked (the call to DB::goto happens in the middle of Perl_pp_goto, not at the very beginning).

Comment: 2. Again, `goto` changes the call stack. You'd have to trace the source code to find exactly what's going on.

Comment: 1. Looks like an answer. When the goto op code is created at compile time, we may put to its struct the file:line info. May you point me to the souce file where the perl compiler creates the `goto` opcode. I will apply your answer.